# what is the type of a pointer to dynamically allocated memory of pointers of type char?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am new to C. I need to allocate memory and store pointers in it. These pointers are of type char. So what is the type of the pointer to that memory? char? or long because addresses are just numbers?

Comment: Addresses are not just numbers. They are numbers with a type.

Comment: The how should I declare that pointer? Just like this: `char *ptr` ? what should be the size for it in `calloc` declaration? just a char size?

Comment: `char **`.  (Pointer to pointer to `char`). 

Pointers are usually just numbers in assembly, but C has a more abstract view of them and even if they end up being just numbers in the generated assembly, C frontends and optimizers treat pointers and numbers as not freely interchangeable.

Comment: the size depends how many chars you need in the allocated memory.  the pointer size is important only if you allocate memory for pointers to pointers .

Comment: @P__J__   I'll store pointers in that allocated memory. So I'll need the size of a pointer, right? say if I will store 3 char pointers then is this right: `char** ptr=(char**) calloc (3, sizeof(char))` ? so every pointer will take a byte here?

Comment: @MohammedElbagoury no. `char** ptr= calloc (3, sizeof(char *))` or better `char** ptr= calloc (3, sizeof(*ptr))`

Comment: @P__J__ Sorry, but what the difference?

Comment: @MohammedElbagoury, there is no real difference in terms of allocated space, using `sizeof(*ptr)` reserves the same memory as `sizeof(char *)` it's used like that to avoid silent errors if you, for some reason, decide to change the type in the future. P.S.: You [should accept one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: sizeof does not deserve any memory

Answer (score 1):

The type is `char**`, pointer to pointer to char, aka double pointer to char.

Note that you wouldn't need to manually allocate space for the pointers if you don't want to.

Take the code:

```
#define POINTER_N 10
//...
char *ptr[POINTER_N]; //array of 10 pointers to char
```

This already reserves space for these 10 pointers, their size is the size of a pointer to char, this size deppends on your system, for a 64 bit system the pointers are 8 bytes, for a 32 bit one it's 4 bytes, this is generic, there can be differences in these values depending on the implementation.

Already having the pointer you only will then need to allocate space for the strings themselves, so for 20 char strings initialized to `\0` you would do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STRING_SIZE 21
//...    
for(size_t i = 0; i < POINTER_N; i++){
    ptr[i] = calloc(STRING_SIZE, sizeof *ptr[0]); //21 char long string
```

This would suffice, note that I'm reserving one extra character for the null terminator.

If you really want to allocate the space for these pointers yourself you would declare a double pointer, and allocate space for the numbers of pointers to char you need:

```
char **ptr = calloc(POINTER_N, sizeof *ptr); // 10 pointers to pointers to char
```

And for the strings:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < POINTER_N; i++){
    ptr[i] = calloc(STRING_SIZE, sizeof **ptr);
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, jesus all my callocs were wrong, I'm surprised no one downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand what you’re asking for, it sounds like this is what you want:

```
#define N 10 // or however many elements you want
...
char **arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * N ); // sizeof *arr == sizeof (char *)
```

Each `arr[i]` will have type `char *`.

If you want an array of `char`, then it would be

```
char *arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * N );
```

and each `arr[i]` will have type `char`.

So, general rule, if you want to allocate an array of type `T`, use

```
T *arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * N );
```

Answer (score 0):

pointers have a type of the pointer to the referenced object. It does not matter how the memory was allocated.

examples

```
void *ptr = malloc(10);  // pointer to void

int c;
void *ptr = &c;          //pointer to void

int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr);  // pointer to integer
int *ptr = &c;                   // pointer to integer

char *cp = malloc(100);          // pointer to char
strcpy(cp, "Hello");

void foo(double *x)              // x is a pointer to double.
{
 /* .... */
} 

double **p;                      //pointer to pointer to double

/* etc etc */
```